# exit code: -1 on codeforces

Tags: exit-code, exitstatus

I submitted a code on codeforces and on the 11th test case i got this-

```
Test: #11, time: 2000 ms., memory: 0 KB, exit code: -1, checker exit code: 0, verdict: TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
Input
999999994 108004280
```

What does exit code: `-1` signify here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should pay more attention to `verdict: TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED`, which means that your program did not fail but worked too long.

I suppose this exit code is just some default value for time limit exceeded cases and not something related to your code.